# Weird display error / Black lines all over the screen when using nvidia driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

**My system:**

> Laptop: Asus K55
>   Grapics driver: Nvidia 340.76 (I also have nvidia prime, so I can switch to intel graphics)
>   GPU: GeForce GT 635M
>   CPU: Intel Core i5-3210M CPU @ 2.501GHz

So, I sudo apt-get updated and upgraded ~3 days ago and since then I'm having these strange problems when using the nvidia drivers (pic related, images suddenly get distorted, menus have these black/gray lines. All applications have this, even unity, so I cannot use it anymore. After a while the screen completely freezes and I have to hard-reset my pc).

Here the image:

[image]

I tried all other nvidia drivers listed in `ubuntu-drivers devices` but none of them fixed the problem. Fortunately I can use the onboard intel drivers using nvidia prime in the `nvidia-settings` which makes it possible to use all applications without these glitches, but using them makes it impossible to use shaders in minecraft.

It seems that https://askubuntu.com/questions/582786/display-error-on-14-10 had the same problem, but noone answered...

Is there any way to use the nvidia drivers again without these black lines all over my screen?

I'm sorry if I misspelled something. English isn't my mother tongue.